# Angular route data tree

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I need to write a component taking the object from routeConfigs. Like that:

```
route.routeConfig.data['info']
```

where route: ActivatedRoute
and routes configured like that:

```
const routes: Routes =
  [{
    path: 'people', data: { info: 'Parent' },
    children: [
      { path: '', component: Component1, data: { info: 'Child1' } },
      { path: ':id', component: Component1, data: { info: 'Child2' } },
      { path: 'new', component: Component1, data: { info: 'Child3' } }
    ]
  }];
```

So I need a function returning me a list of objects/strings which are in config data for current route and for every parent route.
For values above, when I put my component into the component by route `/people/new`
as a result I must have: `["Parent", "Child3"]`

Please help me, mighty All.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the data of current activated Route by injecting `ActivatedRoute` and then using `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data`. But for accessing the parent, you would need to get the parent of the current route using `this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.data`. Since there may be any number of parents, you can recursively traverse the tree and get the data.

Create sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routeconfig-data-hierarchy) for you. Added the necessary code below :

```
let activatedRoute = this.activatedRoute;
this.data = [];
while (activatedRoute) {
  console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.data);
  this.data.push(activatedRoute.snapshot.data);
  activatedRoute = activatedRoute.parent;
}
```

This will update the `this.data` variable with all the values from the data of the route configurations. You can modify it as per your requirements.

Comment: One thing to note is that when using `ActivatedRoute` inside a component it will only give you the route associated with that component. So if you have a component associated with the parent in the question's example it would only show the data for the parent route.

Comment: You can use `activatedRoute.parent` for that scenario.